# Change (reverse) date order in element's attribute value via XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Known:

- Names of an attribute where the date will appear (if there is no date in node, then an attribute won't appear too)
- Names of the element where the attribute is located

**Source code model**

```
<root>
    <parent attr-1="1000" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="10.11.2017">  
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="09.12.2010"> </child>
    </parent>
    <parent attr-1="2222" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="04.06.2016">
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="02.06.2009"> </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**Desired output**

```
<root>
    <parent attr-1="1000" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="2017.11.10">
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="2010.12.09"> </child>
    </parent>
    <parent attr-1="2222" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="2016.06.04">
        <child attr-3="whatever" attr-4="whatever2" DateAttributeChild="2009.06.02"> </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat tedious, but otherwise trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@DateAttributeParent | @DateAttributeChild">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **Thank you, Michael!**